# Is there a way to alter the raspberry image that appears during boot?

Tags: boot, emulation, image

A [glint-box](https://github.com/jefflunt/glint-box) community member recently asked me if there was a way to replace the raspberry image that appears in the top-left corner of the screen during boot to something more NES-centric, such as a 1-UP mushroom.

Anyone know where this image is stored, and if it's not some standard format (.gif, .jpg, etc.) what is involved in swapping it out with something else?

Comment: From what I can see, it would at least require recompiling the kernel. I don't know if you are up to that. I certainly wouldn't. Alternatively you could run `fbi` at boot and display an image onto the screen. Just make sure the image is black in the parts where text will be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you need to recompile a kernel in order to do that.

1. create your image with no more than 224 colors, and 80x80px in size.
2. Save the image as png, and run the following (provided you have `netpbm` installed and kernel source in `/usr/src/linux`):

   > $ pngtopnm logo.png | ppmquant -fs 223 | pnmtoplainpnm > logo_linux_clut224.ppm
   >
   > $ cp logo_linux_clut224.ppm /usr/src/linux/drivers/video/logo/
3. recompile and install the new kernel.

Comment: What happens when I use an image with more than 224 colors for this image and/or it's not 80 x 80px?