# Raspbian boot logo edit

Tags: boot

I will say quickly. How do I edit or remove this logo?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9Iaz3NzJVU

I found something but it does not work (errors)
http://www.rasplay.org/?p=6371

Thanks!

//edit 11:23PM
OK. Solution remove logo:

```
$ sudo su
$ cd /boot
$ nano cmdline.txt
```

add `logo.nologo`

example: `logo.nologo dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait`

How to edit logo?

(sorry my bad english)

Comment: appears to be answered here, http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9072/is-there-a-way-to-alter-the-raspberry-image-that-appears-during-boot

Comment: Or here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/how-to-add-custom-loading-screen

Answer (score -1):

Here is a guy who made it

[Custom Splash Screen for Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)](http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=799)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: We're [trying a new policy with regard to informationless link-only answers here](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538). If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.