# Raspberry Pi 3 four raspberries remove

Tags: boot

How to remove  this 4 raspberries on my Pi 3. I know this is the number of CPU's but i need to remove this ;). I remove most of the messages on boot screen except this one.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the answer: [Raspbian boot logo edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/21999/raspbian-boot-logo-edit)

```
$ sudo su
# cd /boot
# nano cmdline.txt
```

add `logo.nologo` to the end of line.

Comment: Worth noting that `cmdline.txt` **must** remain all one line.

Comment: you can also get rid of splash screen by editing `/boot/config.txt`

Comment: Today i will try this but i this is not working solution.Because this will remove only boot splash screen. I need to remove 4 raspberries on upper left corner they indicates 4 core of cpu ;)

Comment: Ok when i remove consolle=tty1 from this file it's workiing fine for me ;).

Comment: But how to remove Raspbian GNU/Linux 8  message from startup screen ??

Comment: This not remove four raspberries from upper left corner ;)  But thank you ;)

Comment: 4 raspberries is still there ;)