# Remove the raspberry pictures from the top of the console

Tags: terminal

I setup my rPi to start with Console Autologin.

I also start a script from `~/.bashrc`, which runs `tail -f` on a growing file.

The four raspberry icons on top of the console never disappear:

[image: Four raspberries on top of my console]

How can I prevent them from showing up altogether? Alternatively, let them scroll out of screen?

Comment: I searched this site ... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60256/raspberry-pi-3-four-raspberries-remove

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! Searching for "console remove four raspberries" did not yield this result (or any relevant result). "Remove four raspberries" did. Am I wrong to believe this search tool is broken?

Comment: my search was "remove four raspberries" :p

Comment: @JaromandaX the fact that including "console" makes the search fail is terrible. And it makes me look like an idiot who doesn't search before asking :/

Comment: quick, delete your question :p nah, the other question was asked poorly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi logos are done the same way as the Tux penguins used with the normal linux kernel. Try adding this to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
 logo.nologo
```

From: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Remember, `cmdline.txt` must be **all one line**.  Separate parameters with spaces.